# Reactjs focus an input field located in a child component which is inside another child component

Tags: reactjs, input

I am currently trying to focus an input field that is located in  a child component which is inside another child component. consider the following,

Parent.js

child1.js

child2.js

I would like to focus input field in child2 when a button is clicked from parent.js.

Answer (score 1):

I don't say using this technique it's good but you can achieve this by creating a setRef function who get pass by the child 1 to the child 2. Make sure to read this https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html why refs is not the best thing. For me I would use props callback.

But if you really want to use ref this is how you can do. I put the code example here. You can also play with the code here https://codesandbox.io/s/5x8530j3xn

```
class Child2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input ref={this.props.setRef} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child2 setRef={this.props.setRef} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  setRef = ref => {
    this.input = ref;
  };

  focus = () => {
    this.input.focus();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child1 setRef={this.setRef} />
        <button onClick={this.focus}>Go Focus</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the proptype that can be used for ref. thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Just use plain vanilla JavaScript inside a React method.

```
handleFocus () {
  document.getElementById('inputField').focus()
}

<button onClick={this.handleFocus}>My Button</Button>
```

This will focus the input after clicking the button.